# ASP.NET MVC: How to get Request.QueryString value when routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have the following rule

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

And in the controller

```
public ActionResult Forums(int id)
    {
        Response.Write(id); // works
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString["id"]); // doesn't

        return View();
    }
```

How can I get it with Request.QueryString?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to go through [RouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.aspx) to access the routing parameters.

E.g.

```
Routedata.Values["id"]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's exactly what I was looking for. You can't imagine how important this is for building a multi tenancy app. Thanks again.